# Calling internal (Endpoint) function in WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, httpclient

I am using Hangfire to execute recurring jobs in my web API and I use System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath in the "RoutineMethod" function.

But the problem is it throws object null exception.
I searched the problem and found that recurring jobs don't use http threads, they use background threads.

Now to resolve this problem I need to call my internal (endpoint) using httpclient.

But to do that I need to give URL of the Web API (to generate URI). So is there any other way to call internal function using httpclient.

My current code:

```
public static async Task<IHttpActionResult> RoutineTask()
        {
            //It was like this before.
            //await new DemoController().RoutineMethod();
            //await new DemoController().RoutineMethod2();

            //I am planning to do this.
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //But I need to give URI which I don't think is a good idea.
                var uri = new Uri("http://localhost/DemoApp/api/DemoController/RoutineMethod");
                await client.GetAsync(uri);

            }

            return new DemoController().Ok();
        }
```

Comment: Or expose what that endpoint does in a service API that both the assigned endpoint and the jobs can call, given that may be in the same code base. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.  The HttpClient, as its name implies, requires an http connection.

There are no smell issues with storing service connection information in a configuration file.

However, to expand on Nkosi's comment, it appears that since your code can create an instance of DemoController, that it must have a reference to that controller's project or even be in the same project.  I would extract the interesting code into a library or service that all areas needing the information can reference.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand what to do can you elaborate more? Every method described in the question is in the same controller.

Comment: I think the question is about the solution rather than the problem so I asked other question https://stackoverflow.com/q/50501278/9522887

Comment: Should I delete this question?